# Date_Format only returns first value

Tags: sql, date

Trying to convert my variable `edate` to long hand using `date_format`.

This: `$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(events.edate, '%W %D %M %Y')";` produces Tuesday

This: `$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(events.edate, '%W%D%M%Y')";` produces Tuesday29thMarch2022

This: `$query = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(events.edate, '%W-%D-%M-%Y')";` produces Tuesday-29th-March-2022

I want the second version with spaces. Any suggestions please?

Comment: what is definition of table `events` ?

Comment: and can you tag the DBMS which you're using ?

Comment: I assume the first example is a typo? That format doesn’t just produce “Tuesday”. Please provide an example of the exact format you want a date to appear in

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help. After further trial and error I have discovered my error. I was passing the result in an url without using urlencode. I have now added that and it works perfectly.

Thanks for all your responses.